# Ubuntu shutdown fail "* Killing all remaining processes..."

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, shutdown

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu Server.  "reboot" works, but shutdown fails on the `* Killing all remaining processes...` step.  I am using:

```
sudo shutdown now
```

After the failure, indicated by `[fail]` (with "fail" in red), I get this message:

```
 * will now switch to single-user mode
```

with no other error messages.  The user is root after the program exits.

Any ideas about how to trouble-shoot this, or what the problem might be?

The Ubuntu version is 11.10 and I ran `sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude dist-upgrade` before this.

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same issue.

Comment: See if [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/871860) helps. it forced the shutdown, though the red "failed" didn't disappear.

Comment: Does the sudo poweroff make the problem go away?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I've experienced the same, so I had to use halt which worked

```
shutdown -h now
```

Comment: This may require sudo to run

Comment: Is there any explanation on why this is necessary? I have the above problem on a 13.10 distro and even the "shutdown -h now" variant does not work. The only way I can recover from this -- it seems -- is to `reboot -f now` but this skips the whole shutdown process and can't be good for the long-term health of the system.

Comment: This works, though not really sure why the other one fails.

Comment: @user19726 - see other answers for why the simple shutdown "fails" (it is actually not failing, it is simply going to single user mode, rather than straight to halt condition).

Answer (score 21):

From the man pages of `shutdown`:

> ... runlevel 1 is used
>          to put to system into a state where administrative tasks  can  be  per-
>          formed;  this  is  the default if neither the -h or -r flag is given to
>          shutdown."

`shutdown` shuts the system down from a user perspective, as linux is designed as a multi-user system, hence the system-wide message and optional time delay.

*To shutdown the machine, use the -h option.*

And I wouldn't worry about some processes that couldn't be killed in time, which is probably the meaning of the [fail] message you got.

Comment: As a total Noob to Linux, and seeking to up my skills, I prefer to *be worried* about *anything* that fails.  I want to know Linux to the point where I can run in on the open public internet.  That said, I voted for this answer: quotes the man page and explains the default behavior.  I'm tempted to remove the "And I wouldn't worry..." at the end - what value does that add?

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this when trying to reboot with `sudo reboot now`.  `sudo shutdown now` also failed.  In both cases, the system switched to single-user mode and stalled.

Halting the system isn't feasible, since it is remote and I don't want to trek to the basement to turn it back on.  What worked is `sudo shutdown -r 0`.

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 server on an Asus Aspire One netbook.

I know this thread is old, but I'm experiencing this problem with a current distro.

Comment: Thanks for posting this: Ubuntu 13.04 refused to reboot properly without the `shutdown -r 0` command.

Comment: `sudo shutdown -h -r` worked for me, not sure on the differences.

Comment: Voted this up for adding perspective for the person running a physical not-nearby machine - not everyone is in a situation to turn the machine off - I am because: using a VM locally and in the cloud - both places where a machine can be turned off and started via locally available keyboard/cloud control panel.